# Angular site pulls all descriptions as meta content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page that I made with Angular. The page renders correctly, but for some reason it pulls all of the descriptions from the dom elements and makes them into meta content tags. So, for example, I have an image with the description "summary_large_image", but that description is being rendered as `<meta content="summary_large_image" name="twitter:card">` in the head of my rendered html page, instead of just describing the image.

It's not a huge problem, as the page renders correctly, but it will cause issues for SEO, so I would like to fix it. Please let me know if you need more information.

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: it doesn't do that all by itself. Where's the associated code? Best guess is there's a set of `{{}}` missing

Comment: Show us some code...